# Windows phone 7.5 - animate pivotitem loaded event

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to animate a pivotitem when it is loaded in the app. The following code throws an exception - Failed to set property RoutedEvent:

```
<controls:PivotItem x:Name="myPivot">
  <controls:PivotItem.Triggers>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="controls:PivotItem.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myPivot"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               From="0.6" To="1.0" Duration"0:0:1" />
           </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
     </EventTrigger>
  </controls:PivotItem.Triggers>
  ...
</controls:PivotItem>
```

The exact same code works perfectly on a Grid, or a Rectangle. I was under the impression that this will work for any framework element?

Comment: What is the exception you're getting ?

Comment: I'm getting a XamlParseException - failed to assign to property: System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent

Comment: I have a hunch.. Try dropping the `RoutedEvent` attribute ?

Comment: that works, even though I don't know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dropping the `RoutedEvent` attribute

See remarks for the event's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596558%28vs.95%29)

If you don't specify the routed event, it defaults to `Loaded` event.

(This is one of those tricks I learned to do when I get `XamlParseException` although I don't fully understand it.)